# cp: cannot create regular file `../lib/': Is a directory

Tags: ubuntu

I am trying to install simplescalar, I'm at the installing gcc step,but I have faced an error when I type the command

cp ../sslittle-na-sstrix/lib/libc.a ../lib/

but I get the error

cp: cannot create regular file `../lib/': Is a directory

Have any idea?

what does the command exactly do? can I do it without using terminal?

Comment: Do you have write access to the destination folder? usually for installing in default paths you need root access.

Comment: I am using this instruction http://www.igoy.in/simplescalar-installation-made-simple/

Answer (score 2):

I got this error when the directory I was copying to was mistyped and didn't really exist.